# DFT and DWT difference?

Tags: fourier-analysis, image-processing, wavelets

what is the basic difference between the Discrete Fourier Transform and the Wavelet Transform ? and why does JPEG2000 preferred DWT over DCT or DFT ?

Comment: "what is the basic difference" - they use different... wait for it... *basis functions*. DFT uses complex exponentials, while DWT uses wavelet functions.

Comment: Re: second question, see [this](http://www.jpeg.org/.demo/FAQJpeg2k/wavelet-transform.htm).

Comment: Do you know of dsp.stackexchange.com ?

Answer (score 5):

The basic difference is the following: Assume you have a data vector ${\bf x}=(x_1,\ldots, x_N)$ of length $N:=2^n$ that models a function of a real variable $t$ on some finite interval.

In DFT you compute $N$ complex Fourier coefficients of this data vector according to the formula
$$\hat  x_j:={1\over N}\sum_{k=0}^{N-1} x_k\  \omega^{-jk}\ , \qquad\omega:=e^{2\pi i/N}\ ,$$
where FFT (fast Fourier transform) allows you to obtain the $\hat x_j$ in  $O(N\log N)$ operations, and the same number of operations will lead you back to the original ${\bf x}$. The $\hat x_j$ encode all sorts of "distributed" information about ${\bf x}$, but basically you need all of them to recover ${\bf x}$ with sufficient accuracy.

The basic ingredient in DWT is *multiresolution analysis*. Here the $N$ wavelet coefficients, say $w_j$, of the given ${\bf x}$ can be computed in only $O(N)$ operations. The main point, however, is that the $w_j$ encode local information about ${\bf x}$ in a way that makes it possible to discard all $w_j$ with absolute value below a given treshold and still being able to reconstruct ${\bf x}$ with acceptable accuracy. That's what makes DWT so useful in MP3 or in image compressing.

This is accomplished in the following way (I'm describing a toy model of the setup): $w_0$ is just the average of the $x_k$; $w_1$ is the difference between the averages of the  $x_k$ in the first half and the second half of the data vector, $w_2$ is the difference between the averages of the  $x_k$ in the first quarter and the second quarter of the data vector, and $w_3$ is the difference between the averages of the  $x_k$ in the third quarter and the fourth quarter of the data vector, and so on. Finally $w_{N-1}$ is the difference between $x_{N-1}$ and $x_N$. (I have omitted certain weight factors.)

The basis functions of DFT are "discretized sine waves" whereas the basis functions of DWT, the socalled *wavelets*, have very peculiar graphs. But the exact shape of these wavelets plays no rôle in the applications: It is the algebraic structure of the whole setup that is essential.

Answer (score 1):

Sinusoids and wavelets are the [bases](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Basis_%28linear_algebra%29) used in DCT (JPEG) and DWT (JPEG2000), respectively. Lossy compression works by finding a basis (think: alphabet) that represents the signal using as few elements (think: words or letters) as possible. The loss is a result of discarding elements that do not make a significant contribution. To continue the analogy, if you take a sentence in English and discard the vowels you can roughly guess what was meant, while using fewer letters. Lossy compression works in the same way.